# BASH - Automatically rename file as its folder

Tags: bash, download, directory, sh, rename

I have this script that works fine; it renames a download as its folder and then moves it to a specific location.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for filename in /User/Downloads/{SERIES,MOVIES}/*.{mkv,avi,mp4}; do
    new_path="$(dirname $filename).${filename##*.}"
    new_path="${new_path/Downloads/Downloaded/SERIES}"
    echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
    mv "$filename" "$new_path" 
done
```

I want to add some features to it to adapt to other situations, but I don't know how to implement them.

What I want to do is:

1. Currently a file called `Episode1.mkv` is renamed `SERIES.mkv` and moved to `Downloaded/SERIES`. What I want to do is that if the folder is `SERIES - Breaking`, then the file will be renamed as `Breaking.mkv` (so without `SERIES -`).
2. Currently it moves downloaded file only to `Downloaded/SERIES`. What I want to do is that a file is moved to `Downloaded/SERIES` if its folder was `SERIES -`, and to `Downloaded/MOVIES` if its folder was `MOVIES -`.

May someone help me?

Comment: You might want to use `awk` to handle the file name

Comment: May you give me an example?

Comment: `renamedpath=$(echo $filename | awk` ... `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about breaking this out into functions you can call on each type:

```
rename_files() {
  title="${1##*${2} - }"
  for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
    case "${filename##*.}" in
      mkv|avi|mp4)
        new_path="Downloaded/${2}/${title}-$(basename "$filename")"
        echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
        mv "$filename" "$new_path"
        ;;
    esac
  done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "Downloads/${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}
```

Then simply call it as needed:

```
rename_category SERIES
rename_category MOVIES
```

As an example I started with this:

```
.
├── Downloaded
│   ├── MOVIES
│   └── SERIES
├── Downloads
│   ├── MOVIES\ -\ bar
│   │   ├── bar.mp4
│   │   └── foo.mp4
│   ├── MOVIES\ -\ foo
│   │   ├── bar.mp4
│   │   └── foo.mp4
│   ├── SERIES\ -\ bar
│   │   ├── bar.mp4
│   │   └── foo.mp4
│   └── SERIES\ -\ foo
│       ├── bar.mp4
│       └── foo.mp4
├── after.txt
├── before.txt
└── rename_script.sh

8 directories, 11 files
```

After [running the script](https://gist.github.com/sukima/46723e666891c703e7ed) I got:

```
moving Downloads/SERIES - bar/bar.mp4 -> Downloaded/SERIES/bar-bar.mp4
moving Downloads/SERIES - bar/foo.mp4 -> Downloaded/SERIES/bar-foo.mp4
moving Downloads/SERIES - foo/bar.mp4 -> Downloaded/SERIES/foo-bar.mp4
moving Downloads/SERIES - foo/foo.mp4 -> Downloaded/SERIES/foo-foo.mp4
moving Downloads/MOVIES - bar/bar.mp4 -> Downloaded/MOVIES/bar-bar.mp4
moving Downloads/MOVIES - bar/foo.mp4 -> Downloaded/MOVIES/bar-foo.mp4
moving Downloads/MOVIES - foo/bar.mp4 -> Downloaded/MOVIES/foo-bar.mp4
moving Downloads/MOVIES - foo/foo.mp4 -> Downloaded/MOVIES/foo-foo.mp4

.
├── Downloaded
│   ├── MOVIES
│   │   ├── bar-bar.mp4
│   │   ├── bar-foo.mp4
│   │   ├── foo-bar.mp4
│   │   └── foo-foo.mp4
│   └── SERIES
│       ├── bar-bar.mp4
│       ├── bar-foo.mp4
│       ├── foo-bar.mp4
│       └── foo-foo.mp4
├── Downloads
│   ├── MOVIES\ -\ bar
│   ├── MOVIES\ -\ foo
│   ├── SERIES\ -\ bar
│   └── SERIES\ -\ foo
├── after.txt
├── before.txt
└── rename_script.sh

8 directories, 11 files
```

**EDIT**: OP had an interest in going from `…/SERIES - BlahBlah/blah.ext` to `…/SERIES/BlahBlah-blah.ext` *I believe*.

Comment: But is it possible to do this with only one script? I need that can be run automatically after a specific event.

Comment: That is _one_ script: https://gist.github.com/sukima/6b5e799d8f6811885cf0 I'm now very confused.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Now, I tested it and it works: it moves the file depending on the folder name, but there are two problems: the first is that it works only if the folder is `SERIES` or `MOVIES`, not, for example, `SERIES - ExampleName`; the second one is that it doesn't rename the file inside, but it moves only.

Comment: The example is a concept. Fitting it to your needs is an exercise for the student.

Comment: Mmh I'm not a student but I do this as a hobby but OK, I'll try to get by. For now I mark your answer as the best. Thank you!

Comment: I tried for hours but I didn't understand how I can change the pattern excluding 'MOVIES -' and 'SERIES -'.

Comment: Just updated. I think that is right. You've been a bit unclear as to what your actually expecting.

Comment: **#COMMENT1** Sorry if it isn't explained very well. What exactly is not clear? I try to explain better: I have two folders, one called `Downloads` - where downloads are processed - and another one called `Downloaded` - where a download goes when is completed. Every downloads - in `Downloads` - have its unique folder with this pattern `MOVIES - Name` (or `SERIES` doesn't matter). What I want to do is that files downloaded having as extension mp4, mov and avi are: first of all renamed as its unique folder, but without `MOVIES - ` (or `SERIES`);

Comment: **#COMMMENT2** then they are moved to `Downloaded/MOVIES/` if it was `MOVIES` and `Downloaded/SERIES` if i was `SERIES`.

Comment: **#COMMENT3** And of course `Downloads` and `Downloaded` are two different folders of the same level (`User/Downloads` and `User/Downloaded`).

Comment: Unfortunately not. It simply put the file renamed as `MOVIES.mp4` in `/User/Downloaded` - so not `User/Downloaded/MOVIES`. And it works only if the unique folder is named `MOVIES`, not if `MOVIES - SomeName`.

Comment: **EDIT**: sorry I used the wrong script (the old one); with new new one it doesn't do anything (no copy or rename)

Comment: Yes it works! Only one error: if you try testing this file `http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4` and set as unique folder name `MOVIES - FileExample` you can see that the result is `FileExample-big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4`. Is it possible to modify the script so the name is only `FileExample.mp4` ?

Comment: Changed to `new_path="/Downloaded/${2}/${title}.${filename##*.}"` and now is `FileExample.mp4` instead of `FileExample-big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4`. The result is OK but is this a correct solution?

Comment: One last question, if I want to add a second or more folder where the files are moved to, how can I do this? If, for example, I want to move all `rar`, `dat` and `zip` files not to `Downloaded/SERIES` or `Downloaded/MOVIES` folders but to `Archives/RAR`, `Archives/DAT` and `Archives/ZIP` where `Archives` is at the same level of `Downloads` and `Downloaded` -  so not in them - is it possible to do all this with one script or I have to run two different scripts?

Comment: It your script do what ever you want to. It would be no different then typing the commands by hand. This isn’t like some enterprise Java app with tons of developers. There is no right or wrong. How you use/modify the answer here is completely up to you.

Comment: Yeah, Yeah, it is only to know whether it was the right approach; sometimes a wrong code still carries the right result, but that does not mean that there are no errors or unexpected results. Anyway, I do not know how to thank you.

Comment: I made some little changes to adapt to other situations `new_path="/Downloaded/${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"` so now it creates a folder with the same name of the file. But I don't really now how to rename the files - only if more than one with the same extension - with adding numbers, like `FileExample_1.mp4`, etc. I tried with `${n+1`}, `${filename + 1}` but don't works. How can I do this simple thing?